# A French dictionary able to find words using wildcards like " * " or " ? "

Tags: ressources, lexique

Where can I find a french dictionary that will display all the words matching a certain string of letters like "a...eurs" (see the example).

Example of text with some letters missing from a word:
"qui a été fait depuis, **a...eurs**, soit par des moyens plus personnels"

Comment: I can tell you that dictionaries don't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a word list, not a French dictionary :

- http://www.capeutservir.com/mots/
- http://www.fsolver.fr/

Comment: Yes, this is what I am looking for ( http://www.fsolver.fr/?champ=A***EURS ).

Answer (score 2):

Disponible en ligne, un des dictionnaires de référence pour LibreOffice :

*http://www.dicollecte.org/dictionary.php?prj=fr*, dictionnaire collaboratif de mots qui renvoie à plusieurs dictionnaires en ligne pour leurs définitions.

Vous pouvez y rechercher les mots avec les expressions régulières.

Answer (score 1):

[The Oxford Hachette French dictionary](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobisystems.msdict.embedded.wireless.oxford.french&hl=en) is one that I use daily.
[Le Grand Robert de la langue française](http://www.lerobert.com/le-grand-robert/) has both orthographic and phonetic wildcard searches but is a bit pricey.

Answer (score 1):

I think the https://fr.wiktionary.org also does this, using the joker search

Answer (score 0):

La réponse est probablement *ailleurs*.

Parmi les mots possibles:

- aboyeurs
- aigreurs
- ailleurs
- amateurs
- ampleurs
- amuseurs

...